# Distributing tasks between GCE VM instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

I want to run the same Python script with different parameters on several instances on google compute engine. Currently I setup all my instances by creating an instance group. Then I ssh into each machine and start the Python script with the correct parameters.

I'm able to automate setup that's common for all the VMs, such as mounting buckets and so on, by using [startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript). But I still have to ssh into each VM and start the Python script with a different parameter for each VM. Hence, I'm wondering if there's some clever and simple way of running the same Python script with different parameters on each instance.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use metadata: Create your instances separately instead of with an instance group. Make them identical (ie use the same script) except for metadata - use the metadata to give each instance it's unique parameters. In your script, [fetch the metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#querying) to determine how to proceed separately.

Comment: Thank you, that makes things a bit easier :) It'd be nice if something similar could be accomplished with instance groups, so that a list of values are mapped out between the instances